# How to pass a list of objects to a gridview datasource without generating a column error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sqldatasource

I do a basic SQL query to feed data to a Gridview sort event.

```
public DataTable GetDataDataTableGeneric()
{
    string query = "SELECT * FROM Gamer";

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AzureServer"].ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

    conn.Close();
    return dt;
}

protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    // string query= e.SortExpression + " " + GetSortDirection(e.SortExpression);
    // e.SortExpression;
    DataTable dt = GetDataDataTableGeneric();
    dt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + GetSortDirection(e.SortExpression);

    List<DataRow> list = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList();

    GridView1.DataSourceID = null;

    GridView1.DataSource = list;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Since the datasource won't accept a non-enumerable object, I decided to convert the datatable to list.

However, I get this error:

> 'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a property with the name 'Id'.

Is there a way to generate a list and avoid the error?

**UPDATE**
Function:

```
        protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {

        DataTable dt = GetDataDataTableGeneric();
        dt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + GetSortDirection(e.SortExpression);
    //    List<Gamer> list = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList();
        List<Gamer> list = (from DataRow row in dt.Rows
         select new Gamer
         {
             //assign properties here
             Id = Convert.ToInt32(row["Id"]),
             UserID = Convert.ToInt32(row["UserID"]),
             Level = Convert.ToInt32(row["Level"]),
             Loyalty = Convert.ToInt32(row["Loyalty"]),
             Experience = Convert.ToInt32(row["Experience"]),
             OverallPoints = Convert.ToInt32(row["OverallPoints"]),
             OverallBets = Convert.ToInt32(row["OverallBets"]),
             Login = row["Login"].ToString()

         }).ToList();

        GridView1.DataSourceID = null;
        GridView1.DataSource = list;
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
```

Error

> The data source does not support sorting.

The following solution failed too. Resulting in the same sorting problem.

```
    protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {

       DataTable dt = GetDataDataTableGeneric();
        dt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + GetSortDirection(e.SortExpression);
        List<Gamer> list = (from DataRow row in dt.Rows
         select new Gamer
         {
             //assign properties here
             Id = Convert.ToInt32(row["Id"]),
             UserID = Convert.ToInt32(row["UserID"]),
             Level = Convert.ToInt32(row["Level"]),
             Loyalty = Convert.ToInt32(row["Loyalty"]),
             Experience = Convert.ToInt32(row["Experience"]),
             OverallPoints = Convert.ToInt32(row["OverallPoints"]),
             OverallBets = Convert.ToInt32(row["OverallBets"]),
             Login = row["Login"].ToString()

         }).ToList();
        DataTable dt2 = ConvertToDataTable(list);
        GridView1.DataSourceID = null;
        GridView1.DataSource = dt2;
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }


    private DataTable ConvertToDataTable<T>(IList<T> data)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
        {
            table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
        }
        foreach (T item in data)
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
            {
                row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
            }
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return table;
    }
```

The following solution has failed to work too:

```
        string cmd = "SELECT * FROM Gamer ORDER BY "+ e.SortExpression + " " + GetSortDirection(e.SortExpression);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {

            SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, connection);

            sqlAdapter.Fill(ds);
        }
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely enough to make it work all you need is to put an empty eventhandler.

```
 protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
        {}
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not makes sense, what is actually getting achieved by converting it to `List<DataRow>` and you are not converting it to `List<Gamer>`, so this way it woldn't work.

What you can do is directly bind it with datatable:

```
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

or the other way around is to create a class which will be a `DTO` against your table :

```
public class Gamer
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
}
```

and then your code, you would create a `List<Gamer>` from the `DataTable` or from Data Access you can directly return `List<Gamer>`.

Your method code would look like this if you follow the first approach:

```
protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{

    DataTable dt = GetDataDataTableGeneric();
    dt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + GetSortDirection(e.SortExpression);

    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I used that solution before. The error that you get if you do this is 'Data source doesnt support sorting'. That is because the datasource property accepts a class that is IEnumberable. Thats the reason I used casting. I created  gamer class but I have a casting issue:  List<Gamer> list = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList();   I dont know how to make that conversion and my linq to sql knowledge isnt good.

Answer (score 0):

You can use several options but the easiest one

```
    DataTable dt = GetDataDataTableGeneric();
    dt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + GetSortDirection(e.SortExpression);
GridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Or you can use following function for dynamically create table from Query and then assign that to GridView

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        NorthwindEntities entity = new NorthwindEntities();
        var db1 = (from ordermst in entity.Orders
                    where ordermst.ShipCountry.Equals("Finland")
                    select new
                    {
                        CustomerID = ordermst.CustomerID,
                        OrderID = ordermst.OrderID
                    }).Take(10).ToList();
        DataTable dt = ConvertToDataTable(db1);
        GvOrder.DataSource = dt;
        GvOrder.DataBind();
 
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        dt1 = GvOrder.DataSource as DataTable;
        GvOrder1.DataSource = dt1;
        GvOrder1.DataBind();
 
    }
}
 
private DataTable ConvertToDataTable<T>(IList<T> data)
{
    PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
    {
        table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
    }
    foreach (T item in data)
    {
        DataRow row = table.NewRow();
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
        {
            row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
        }
        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    return table;
}
```

Comment: I got this error: The data source does not support sorting.  After using both of your code pieces. Your second solution is updated in my answer above.